# HAProxy decreasing throughput

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unix, load-balancing, haproxy

I think I am doing something wrong with HAProxy conf because my throughput drops to 25% in a real-world test done with HAProxy and one single AWS instance. Following is my relevant (extremely simple) configuration:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     20000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m

timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 30000
frontend localnodes
    bind *:80
    mode http
    default_backend nodes
backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    hash-type consistent
    option httpchk /health
    server w1 xx.xx.xx.xx:80 check id 1
```

I had enabled logging. A typical entry in log looks like this:

```
 Dec  2 09:29:05 localhost haproxy[2782]: xx.xx.xx.xx:43908
 [02/Dec/2016:09:29:05.940] localnodes nodes/w1 38/0/0/1/41 200 130 - -
 ---- 36/36/12/2/0 0/0 "GET /ep?key=123&message=XXQSYI HTTP/1.1" Dec  2 09:29:05 localhost haproxy[2782]: xx.xx.xx.xx:43920
 [02/Dec/2016:09:29:05.941] localnodes nodes/web01 39/0/0/0/40 200 160
 - - ---- 35/35/11/0/0 0/0 "GET /q1?key=123&val=123 HTTP/1.1" Dec  2 09:29:05 localhost haproxy[2782]: xx.xx.xx.xx:43933
 [02/Dec/2016:09:29:05.955] localnodes nodes/web01 24/0/0/1/26 200 134
 - - ---- 34/34/11/1/0 0/0 "GET /q1?key=123&val=123 HTTP/1.1"
```

My throughput is 25% of what a direct traffic to my instance would be. This is terrible performance. Am I doing something really wrong?

**EDIT**
Going down the log, some logs clearly show that time taken to reach server from HAProxy is too high

```
Dec  2 10:56:59 localhost haproxy[25988]: xx.xx.xx.xx:39789 [02/Dec/2016:10:56:58.729] main app/app1 0/0/1000/1/1002 200 449 - - ---- 13/13/13/7/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Dec  2 10:56:59 localhost haproxy[25988]: xx.xx.xx.xx:39803 [02/Dec/2016:10:56:58.730] main app/app1 0/0/999/1/1000 200 377 - - ---- 12/12/12/7/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
Dec  2 10:56:59 localhost haproxy[25988]: xx.xx.xx.xx:39804 [02/Dec/2016:10:56:58.730] main app/app1 0/0/999/1/1000 200 277 - - ---- 11/11/11/7/0 0/0 "GET / HTTP/1.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

From your log, most of your time is being spent connecting to the server. For example, you spend 1000, 999 and 999 milliseconds connecting. This may have to do with that you are closing the connection to the server immediately after each transaction by using `option http-server-close`. So, the TCP connection has to be re-established each time (if this is the same client between requests).

Overall, it looks like you're spending about 1 second per request, which doesn't sound horrible to me. What were you seeing before using HAProxy?